# Prevent CSS column wrap inside grid rows on Webkit

Tags: css, webkit

My outside container has the `columns: 2` style.

The content of that is a grid with two columns itself, the labels on one side and the input on the right. The idea is that when the viewport is large enough, the content is split in two columns, and when it's small it's only one column.

It works well on Chrome, but in Safari there is an annoying behavior. The column wraps inside my grid rows.

[I created a codepen that demonstrates the problem](https://codepen.io/jerometremblay/pen/YzvemEw). Resize the text area to trigger column wrap.

In Chrome rows are wrapped whole:
[image: Expected behaviour on Chrome]

In Safari, rows are split across columns:
[image: Problem on Safari]

I expected this to work

```or-tag-here
input, textarea, label {
  /* This has no apparent effect */
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

but no luck.

Any hint?

Comment: I'm surprised it works like it does (FF, Chrome) as you split a `grid` over two `columns`. Cudos for that! Maybe [`box-decoration-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break) will work for this. But why not make `.columns` a grid too and override `grid-template-columns` for narrow viewports? Avoiding the issue as a whole. BTW, not using Safari, can't check anything for you...

Comment: Thank you. I tried box-decoration-break and did not work. 

As for making the whole thing a 4-columns grid,  notice that some fields can be of different size (such as the text area). I want the heights to be independant in the two columns. 

Also, I could not figure out how to order the fields first in column 1, then in column 2. I always got a left to right before next row layout.